# Loop through Header File when you don't know contents

Tags: c

I'll do my best to explain the problem as simply as possible, but this is may be a complicated question so please feel free to ask for clarification. Basically I want to take a header file, find a struct in it with the same name as the header file and print out all contents in the header file in a specific format. A header file would look something like this:

fileName.h:

```
struct 1{
   unsigned int a;
};

struct 2{
   struct 3; #from another header
};

struct fileName{
    struct 1 1a;
    struct 2 2a;
    unsigned int b;
};
```

I am not sure where to even start with this, I can loop through a header and print all contents if I treat it like a text file but that prints out everything and not in the way I need. I need it to look something like this:

```
fileName
{
    1a.a
    bitmask
    shift
}
```

I can get the filename as a "string" by taking argv[1] and looping through it while saving all but the .h to a another char[] with a \0 on it. Assume you don't know the filename when it's passed to the program, how do I skip past everything to go straight to the fileName struct and loop through it?

The next step is nested as the header files can have includes to other header files. Given a thing, be it a struct or a data type, in fileName.h that comes from someOtherFile.h, how do I make an if to go to the someOtherFile.h and loop through that file in the same fashion as before?

```
struct fileName{
     struct 1 a;
};

file someOtherFile:
struct 1{
     char e;
};

output:
```

```
fileName
{
    "a.e"
    [bitmask]
    [shift]
}
```

Is this even possible in C? From my inability to find things online I'm starting to feel it might be, perhaps C is the wrong language to do this in but the files are header files no matter what so I thought C would be the best fit for it as you can just grab the data exactly as opposed to having to parse it from a scan. I assure you I wouldn't turn to making a post like this unless I looked extensively elsewhere, though you can likely see why my account is named the way it is now.

Comment: it is possible.. but it requires implementing a full C-lexer and simplified parser. It's not a task for a beginner

Comment: You basically want reflection, which is not supported in C.  Your best bet will probably be to write that header file in a different language that is easier to parse.  (It's much easier to generate valid C code from a scripting language, rather than trying to go the other direction by parsing C.)

Comment: Python can process itself as Abstract Syntax Tree. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: @0x5453 I can't rewrite the headers, they're provided to me and are updated from time to time hence my "not knowing" what's in them. I can hard code a list all the header files to be included so the user only would need to update that list, but I can't change the files themselves.

Comment: @tstanisl I'm not sure what you mean by process itself, are you saying I can pass a header file to this ast thing and it can parse it into a tree? It'll take me a little while to read through all that, thank you for the material as it looks like it will be fun to play around with. However, I already knew how to do this problem in a different language, I was asking if it was possible in C, and if so how.

Comment: Doing that **correctly** in C is a very complex task. Don't do it. I expect that the `struct`s that you are interested in are defined using some predictable pattern. I could simplify parsing.  Consider using `awk`/`sed`/even `grep` to extract valid information. There are C parser written in Python in the wild but I don't know how reliable are they.

Comment: @tstanisl predictable indeed, the struct I am interested in is always the same name as the file. You said correctly in C is a complex task, so the obvious follow up questions are; what is that correct method (the c-lexer you mentioned?) and is there an incorrect method that works?